# C++ DispInvoke fails to find member

Tags: c++, automation, idispatch

The scenario is this:

- I have a COM object to ask questions. Name it ICom.
- The COM object requires me to implement an IDispatch , descendant of , say, IComEvents, that notifies me for events.
- I implement an IDispatch and connect it to the COM interface.

So far so good. My IComEvents descentant's Invoke() is called when the events occur.

The point is now that I must manually parse Invoke() parameters. For example, if a notification function is HRESULT OnMouseHit(int x), I have to detect this function from the DispID, then call it manually, for example

```
if (dispIdMember == 0xfa)
 {
 OnMouseHit(pDispParams->rgvarg[0].pIntVal); 
 }
```

I would have to do it for all the functions I want to implement. However I saw the DispInvoke() function which presumably will automatically do this for me and call the appropriate overloaded method for the dispId, with the correct parameters:

```
DispInvoke(this,m_ptinfo,dispIdMember,wFlags,pDispParams,pVarResult,pExcepInfo,puArgErr);
```

How do I generate m_ptinfo? By calling LoadRegTypeLib with the libid of the COM object, and then ITypeLib::GetTypeInfoOfGuid() with the IID of IComEvents. However, DispInvoke() always returns "member not found".

What would be wrong?  I expect DispInvoke to parse the type information, find the member function name from the DispID and then use the "this" pointer to get the function address from the vtbl.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.
Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `IComEvents` a dual interface or a dispinterface? If it is a pure dispinterface it doesn't have a vtable. `DispInvoke` requires the interface to have a vtable (ie that it is a dual interface).

Comment: I see. It must be an interface without a vtable. But what would be the use of DispInvoke then? Almost all notification interfaces in Windows are built the same way.

Comment: @Michael I assume DispInvoke is meant as an aid for implementing ordinary dual interfaces (where the implementer is generally also the creator of the interface) rather than event (callback, notification) interfaces, where the implementer is specifically not the creator of the interface. Note that normally there is no loss in making an interface dual rather than dispinterface, but for an event interface making it dual would mean than scripting languages (which can't create vtables) wouldn't be able to receive the events.